# Error updating from onesignal 3.x.x to 4.x.x sdk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onesignal

I am a newbie in android studio/java programming, I have an already built source code for a webview application.
I updated the onesignal sdk from 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.0.0, 3.99.99]' to the 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]', but I got an error in my app.java when trying to sync the gradle and building the app.

[error while building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQbP1.png)

**My build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.14.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.ortho.fixar'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
        multiDexEnabled true

//        manifestPlaceholders = [
//                onesignal_app_id: '',
//                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE']
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("")
            storePassword ""
            keyAlias "keystore"
            keyPassword ""
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.1'
    //implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$gps_version"
    //implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$gps_version"
    //implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$gps_version"
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**My app.java:**

```
package com.ortho.fixar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;
import com.ortho.fixar.activity.MainActivity;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

      private String push_url = null;
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (Config.ANALYTICS_ID.length() > 0) {
            mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        }

        //OneSignal Push
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getString(R.string.onesignal_app_id)))
            OneSignal.init(this, "REMOTE", getString(R.string.onesignal_app_id), new NotificationHandler());
    }

    // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it or one is received while the app is running.
    private class NotificationHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
            try {
                JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

                String webViewUrl = (data != null) ? data.optString("url", null) : null;
                String browserUrl = result.notification.payload.launchURL;

                if (webViewUrl != null || browserUrl != null) {
                    if (browserUrl != null || result.notification.isAppInFocus) {
                        browserUrl = (browserUrl == null) ? webViewUrl : browserUrl;
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(browserUrl));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                        Log.v("INFO", "Received notification while app was on foreground or url for browser");
                    } else {
                        push_url = webViewUrl;
                    }
                } else if (!result.notification.isAppInFocus) {
                    Intent mainIntent;
                    mainIntent = new Intent(App.this, MainActivity.class);
                    mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                }


            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public synchronized String getPushUrl(){
        String url = push_url;
        push_url = null;
        return url;
    }

    public synchronized void setPushUrl(String url){
        this.push_url = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

OneSignal has a [guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v7.0/docs/40-api-android-native) for the migration from SDK 3.x to 4.x

Also you may have a look over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74808433/7360275), it could be a useful implementation.